# I need to write this expression in Kmap but I dont how to write '(A+C) correctly

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have to do synthesis of combinational logic circuit from this expression first I have to do K map (karnaugh) and I want to know how can I correctly do it. The expression is (A+'B)*('C+D)*'(A+C)
Tip: A+C is in complement.

Comment: de Morgan’s Theorem '(A+C)='A.'B

Comment: How can I write in Kmap?

Comment: The same way you write for other expressions. Suppose in all (A+'B) you will write $0$ in Kmap. Similarly In all 'A and all 'C you write $0$. Think of 'A and 'C and a separate POS.

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: I have solved it here http://www.32x8.com/pos4_____A-B-C-D_____m_0-1___________option-2_____899788975274834292792

Comment: (A+'B)('C+D)'(A+C)=(A+'B)('C+D)('A'C)=$(A+'B)('C+D)('A)('C)$ So there are 4 products in your expression

Comment: Hmm okay I think I got it

Comment: I suppose you need to go through basics of Kmap

Comment: @NamanJain Is $'A$ a common notation for not $A$, I never see this before, is there any reference for it $\dots$

Comment: Yes it's a symbol for not